# fatal error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'MSXML6.dll': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, windows-11

Cannot open type library file: 'MSXML6.dll': No such file or directory

I have found this .dll in these paths:

- C:\Windows\System32\
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
- C:\Windows\Temp\527D94AF-D053-4381-B105-0D815D53791E\wow64_microsoft-windows-msxml60_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.16299.1087_none_9a3f4591fce26e52\
- C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-msxml60_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.16299.1087_none_9a3f4591fce26e52\
- C:\Windows\System32\

Comment: #import "c:\windows\system32\msxml6.dll"

Comment: How are you using this dll? As a COM server? Are you importing it, or having problems at runtime? Did you register the dll or created a manifest? So many things that can go wrong, we need more details to help you.

Comment: I am including the 'MSXML6.dll' in my code using the '#import "MSXML6.dll" named_guids '. However, when I attempt to build my project, I encounter this error.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible sample of your project?